# Excel is not opening in C#

Tags: c#

I tried opening excel but it doesn't work.... Can Anyone help me ....

```
        string path = Session["dir"].ToString() + "\\" + e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: It seems that this code is executed on an ASP.NET site. What is the path value used to open the excel file?

Comment: E:\Sriram\Project\sgportalapplication\PO\1.xls

Comment: Of course this file is located on the web server and you have Excel installed there right?

Comment: Yes .. I could open a PDf and Image file but not excel/word ....

Comment: Any errors or exceptions you got?

Comment: Nope... But I somehow worked out with this coding which works fine ...  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";
            startInfo.Arguments = System.IO.Path.Combine(Session["dir"].ToString(), e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Process.Start(startInfo);

Answer (score 1):

The code tries to activate a COM object. One thing to check would be if the user that is configured for the application pool in IIS has Launch and Activation Permisions in the DCOM Config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove close and quit?
If it is not helping try this:

```
// Start a new workbook in Excel.
        var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = true };
        var excelWorkBooks = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks)excel.Workbooks;
        var workbookAdd = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)excelWorkBooks.Add(); // XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet

        var worksheets = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets)workbookAdd.Worksheets;
        var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)worksheets.Item[1];
        sheet.Visible = XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
```